# How to fix 'variable lengths differ' error?

Tags: r, stat

This is my code:

```r
Income.x1 <- ifelse(Income ==1, "L", ifelse(Income == 2, "M",ifelse(Income == 3, "H",NA)))
gender.x2 <- ifelse(Gender==1, "M",ifelse(Gender == 2, "F",NA))
Happy.x3 <- ifelse(Happy==1,"A",ifelse(Happy==2,"B",ifelse(Happy==3,"C",NA)))

regr.x = lm(TVhours ~ Income.x1 + Happy.x3+ gender.x2)
sRegr.5 = summary(regr.x);sRegr.5
```

This is my error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = TVhours ~ Income.x1 + Happy.x3 +  :
> variable lengths differ (found for 'gender.x2')

why is there a variable length issue?

Comment: Hi Firas, welcome to SO. It is better to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. As you haven't provided a copy of Income, Gender, and Happy, it's only possible to guess what is causing your issue. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably just have more (less) observations in one variable, check the length of every variable involved in your linear regression model. See how I can get the same error with:

```
x1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
x2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

length(x1)
length(x2)

lm(x1~x2)
```

Console output:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = x1 ~ x2, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'x2')
```